# Can I access SharePoint 2013 app with SharePoint Designer?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-addin

I am creating an app that contains quite a few colums/content types/lists. I thought after deploying the app to see if I could do some fast editing with SharePoint Designer but it seems it cannot connect. I get the message:

> This web site has been configured to disallow editing with SharePoint
>   Designer.

Is there a setting I can define in my app to allow sharepoint designer?
Please note I am deploying on SharePoint Online.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my experience you cannot access App Webs in SharePoint Designer. The only reference I can find that discusses this is a comment by the author of [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdesigner/archive/2012/11/22/example-workflow-with-app-step-usage.aspx) on the SharePoint Designer team blog, "App Web is blocked in SPD 2013, which is by design..."

**Update (02/16)**

I found [another blog post](http://blogs.technet.com/b/mspfe/archive/2013/01/31/understanding-sharepoint-apps-as-an-it-pro.aspx) that states:

> SharePoint components are deployed to a special sub Web of the host
>   web called the App Web.  It uses a new site definition in SharePoint
>   2013 and is configured in such a way that end users cannot manipulate
>   app webs using a browser or SharePoint Designer, to avoid breaking of
>   the Apps.  Pretty much everything is deployed to the app web.

**End Update**

Comment: You are probably right. I cannot track any other documentation stating otherwise.