# Can't create list workflows with SharePoint Designer

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-online, provider-hosted-app

I have created a SharePoint Provider Hosted App. This app uses SharePoint lists for storing the data.

Now I want to create a simple list workflow depending on a state in the SharePoint list. 
But when I want to access the SharePoint site (developer dashboard) it is not possible. SharePoint designer tells me that the website is not allowed to access them with SharePoint Designer.

So my question is: How can I enable the feature or is it not possible to create workflows on a list that is hosted in a provider hosted app?

Comment: The list is in the app-web if I understand correctly? Not in the provider-hosted part

Comment: If so, your question is a duplicate of http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/84014/can-i-access-sharepoint-2013-app-with-sharepoint-designer